# VueJS получить информацию перед разворачиванием строки?

Tags: ajax, vue.js

Использую [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/) компонент таблицы.
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на "Show Details", сначало отправлялся GET запрос на получение данных, и после успешного получения, открывалась строка с этими данными?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что именно непонятно? На клике на кнопку делаете Ajax запрос, как он отработал добавляете и выводите div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример реализации: [github](https://github.com/idushii/vue-table-line-load).

Вынесены отдельно функции получения данных с сервера (loadData) и функция нажатия на кнопку для открытия данных (details).

Функция обработки нажатия принимает два параметра: row ( текущая строка таблицы ) и type ( тип нажатия, а именно открытие или закрытие ).

Для реализации асинхронности использовались promise`ы.

Процесс подгрузки данных:

[image: процесс подгрузки]

Загруженные данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рабочий пример доступен по ссылке https://idushii.github.io/vue-table-line-load/

Comment: добавь важные участки кода непосредственно в ответ, не только ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Для GET (и других) запросов я предлагаю вам использовать библиотеку `axios`.

Вот как примерно все это будет выглядеть:

```
    ...
    methods: {
      showDetails (id) {
         //метод вызывается при нажатии на кнопку "Show Details"
         //в метод можно передать id элемента, по которому необходимо запросить информацию
         axios.get('/user', {
           params: {
             id      //в параметрах можно передать id запрашиваемого элемента (или/и любую другую требуемую информацию для запроса данных)
           }
         })
         .then(response => {
           // если запрос данных произошел успешно, то открываем строку с этими данными
         })
         .catch(error => {
           //иначе обрабатываем ошибку 
         });      
      }
    }
    ...
```

Подробнее про библиотеку `axios` прочитайте [тут](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Answer (score 0):

Объявите свой метод, внутри которого выполняйте запрос и раскрывайте блок с деталями.

Например, пусть есть метод `tooggleRow`, тогда в шаблоне навешиваем его на событие клика:

```
<b-button size="sm" @click.stop="toogleRow(row)" class="mr-2">
    {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Details
</b-button>
```

Сам метод может иметь примерно следующее содержание:

```
methods: {
    toogleRow(row) {
        // При сворачивании скрываем блок без запроса
        if (row.item._showDetails) {
            row.toggleDetails();
            return;
        }

        // При разворачивании выполняем запрос
        fetch('/details.json')
            .then(function (res) {
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                // Собираем данные
                row.item.isActive = res.isActive;
                row.item.age = res.age;

                // Разворачиваем детали
                row.toggleDetails();
            });
    }
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/maximzasorin/dx7ss5bv/